# Handing Arrays in soap webservice testing using fitnesse

Tags: soap, fitnesse, fitnesse-slim, fixture

Is there a way to dynamically create tables in wiki?

Usecase : I'm trying to mimic similar to soap sonar in fitnesse. SOAP SOANR 1. Once we import the wsdl, soap sonar generates inputs for operations in wsdl. 2. Choose a operation, Enter input and then execute the operation. 3. In case of arrays, we can select size of array and enter values in respective array.

Fitnesse 1. I'm able to achieve point 1 using soapui jars. 2. This i'm able to achieve using xmlhttptest fixture

I'm stuck in 3rd point. Is there a way i can do this in fitnesse? (My idea is from point 1, i can get sample input for each operation, from which i will get to know that there are arrays/complex types present in input.xml but how do we represent this in wiki dynamically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

What I've done in the past is use [ListFixture](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.ListFixtureTest.html) (and [MapFixture](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.MapFixtureTest.html)) to dynamically fill a List (and Map/Hashes for each element's properties) and then use these as input values to a XmlHttpTest's [feature to create the body to be sent using a FreeMarker template](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.HttpTests.HttpPost3UsingFreemarkerTemplateTest.html) (which allows iteration over a list, which I use to create elements in the array based on the list).

But this gets quite complex quickly. Is that level of flexibility truly required? I found that quite often hard coding the number of elements in arrays/lists in the wiki is simpler to do and makes the test far easier to understand/maintain.

I most cases I prefer to create a script (or scenario) with the right number of elements for the test case(s) in with the request in the wiki page. The use of scenarios allows me to test with different values (but the same number of elements). Another element count gets its own script/scenario.

Being able to dynamically change the number of elements is only worthwhile if you need to test for many different counts, otherwise the added complexity of dynamically creating the body is just not worth it.